# Detect TFS Build vs. Visual Studio build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild

Is it possible to detect whether or not the current build is executing from Visual Studio rather than an automated build with TFS without creating a separate solution configuration? I'm wondering if I can exclude certain Post Build Events if the build is running on TFS 2013, but if possible I would like to avoid a whole separate configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to edit the CSProj file: just use CMD.EXE syntax in Visual Studio Post-Build events

You can test if running inside Visual Studio

```
IF "$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)"=="true" (
  …
)
```

or inside TFS Build (2013 or later)

```
IF "$(TF_BUILD)"=="True" (
  …
)
```

See the discussion a
[TFS 2010 Build Automation and post-build event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068884/tfs-2010-build-automation-and-post-build-event/6137142#6137142) and [Team Foundation Build environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, and I finally found out how:

1. Unload the project in question, that has a PostBuildEvent defined.
2. Edit the .csproj file.
3. Locate the PostBuildEvent XML element, and add a Condition attribute like the following:

   `<PostBuildEvent Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'">`

At this point the PostBuildEvent will only execute when built with Visual Studio.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791034/73031) and other answers to that question were helpful.

This particular property is briefly mentioned on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx) MSDN page as well.