# Run batch script before Debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, post-build-event, pre-build-event

I want to run a batch script every time before starting program for debugging.

For the build events, such functionality is realized using pre-build event, post-build event.

For actual debugging, I could not find any pre-Debug, post-Debug events.

How to realize this scenario?

I am using VS2008, .net framework 3.5, c# application.

I am opposed to idea of creating some extra lines of code within the application that would fire-up external batch file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I realise you wished to avoid additional code, but in your `Main` function you could use [`Debugger.IsAttached()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) to kick off your work for you.

For example:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\myBatchFile.bat");
}
```

Comment: A slightly cleaner way of doing this would be to create a separate project that calls `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\myBatchFile.bat");`, then run multiple startup projects with your new project calling the batch file. Then you avoid changing your production code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a VS macro.

I had the same issue and this is the best I came with so far

```
Dim MustUpdateDB As Boolean

    Private Sub DebuggerEvents_OnEnterRunMode(ByVal Reason As EnvDTE.dbgEventReason) Handles DebuggerEvents.OnEnterRunMode
        If (MustUpdateDB) Then
            MsgBox("Start debug operation", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "TITLE")
            REM DO WHATEVER COMMAND HERE
            REM  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\listfiles.bat")
            MustUpdateDB = False
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildDone(ByVal Scope As EnvDTE.vsBuildScope, ByVal Action As EnvDTE.vsBuildAction) Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildDone
        MsgBox("Build Done", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Title")
        MustUpdateDB = True
    End Sub
```

There is a pretty good explanation on how to add event handlers to a macro
 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228948.aspx)

The only issue I have so far is to figure out how to get the currently debugged application active directory

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution that worked for me (in VS 2017) was to create a batch file that does the command(s) that should run before debugging, and also include as the last line some parameters to be passed via command-line, such as this:

```
rem Place the command(s) you need here:
xcopy pristine.file changed.file

rem Now process passed commands - a few extra placeholders shouldn't hurt anything, to
rem allow for some extra command-line parameters
%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7
```

Now in the debugging properties, set the 'Command' to your batch file, and for 'Command Arguments' include $(TargetPath) as the first argument, followed by any arguments your program uses or needs:

```
$(TargetPath) my command args
```

YMMV, but for my simple needs this seems to be working well.

Answer (score -2):

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug mkdir c:\mydir
```

You should check out... [How to run Visual Studio post-build events for debug build only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only)

Comment: Actually I need something that is fired just before debug, not after post build event. I have to run a script every time the tool is launched in debug mode. Even though there is no change in source code (and hence no build, only tool launch).

Comment: @Tilak, were you able to find some solution for this?

Answer (score -3):

So, you have a .bat file that you want to run via the pre-build event?
Try to specify full path to your batch file in the pre-build event command e.g.

```
cmd /c C:\Path\to\foo.bat
```

or

```
cmd C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Path\to\foo.bat
```

Comment: You have probably completely misunderstood the question.. Just keep in mind that "Pre/Post-build" events doesn't run before EVERY debugging start. For ex, if you haven't made any change to your code after last build, the build wont be triggered before debug.