# batchfile is not running in prebuild event vs2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, copy

I had a batch command that copies multiple files from source to destination

```
for %I in ( C:\Source\abc.txt C:\Source\cba.txt) do copy %I C:\Destination
```

if we give the command in buildevent->prebuild event ->commandline of visual studio 2013

Its  throwing me the error

```
error MSB3073: The command "for %I in ( C:\Source\abc.txt C:\Source\cba.txt) do xcopy %I C:\Destination :VCEnd" exited with code 255.
```

If we run the command in command prompt its  successfully copied.

Why this is throwing the error in vs 2013 ?

Thanks 
Phani

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

From a quick search around, it would seem that error code `255` means that it is failing to find the file.

- [ILMerge - the command exited with code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859588/ilmerge-the-command-exited-with-code-255)
- [Copy task, MSB3073, exit code 255](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c9fe273-4882-4d38-a863-4a8c133a09a0/copy-task-msb3073-exit-code-255?forum=msbuild)

> ERROR_EA_LIST_INCONSISTENT
>   255 (0xFF)
>   The extended attributes are inconsistent.

#### Resolution

Try using absolute paths `"%~fI"` in the command and the flag `/Y` to prevent copy prompts.

```
for %I in ("C:\Source\abc.txt" "C:\Source\cba.txt") do xcopy "%~fI" "C:\Destination" /Y
```

May also be experiencing file or directory prompt which can be resolved with `echo d |`

```
for %I in ("C:\Source\abc.txt" "C:\Source\cba.txt") do echo d | xcopy "%~fI" "C:\Destination" /Y
```

Comment: Still facing the same error ....but am able to run the command through command line..Is it any problem with my visual studio 2013?

Comment: According to MSDN: [`Because the '%' character is reserved by MSBuild, if you specify an environment variable replace each % escape character with the %25 hexadecimal escape sequence. For example, replace %WINDIR% with %25WINDIR%25. MSBuild replaces each %25 sequence with the % character before it accesses the environment variable.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx) try `for %25I in ("C:\Source\abc.txt" "C:\Source\cba.txt") do echo d | xcopy "%25~fI" "C:\Destination" /Y`  If that does not work, `for` loops may just not work unless in a batch file for visual studio.