# Running jake on appharbor

Tags: appharbor, jake

I have a post build task that I run on my MVC 3 project, 'jake build', that combines a bunch of coffee script files and runs some tests using Phantom.js.

I don't expect appharbor to run this when I deploy, but it is trying to.  It is of course failing because node, jake, and any number of other node modules are not installed.  Is there a way to have this post build process run on my local machine when I build but have appharbor ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out using this questions:  [How to run Visual Studio post-build events for debug build only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only)

You can do this in the ide:
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug jake build

or this in the source of your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <PostBuildEvent>start gpedit</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```