# Different Postbuilds for different Configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run Visual Studio post-build events for debug build only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only)

I want to execute a postbuild command when compiling my project as Release. If Debug is set, these Postbuilds should not be executed. How to do this? Visual Studio uses the same Pre- and Postbuild for all Configurations

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only

Comment: Thanks Jesse, sry for doublepost