# Visual Studio 2012: How to perform a conditional post-build event

Tags: macros, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event, visual-studio-macros

How do I perform a conditional post-build event?  Specifically, I would like to only execute the post-build event command line for the debug release but not for the release build.

I did not see any way in a project's properties' Build Event page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Visual Studio post-build events for debug build only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to do some checking against the $ConfigurationName property.

This SO post has lots of examples:
[How to run Visual Studio post-build events for debug build only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only)