# Multi-Line Visual Studio conditional prebuild event returns 255

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, csproj, pre-build-event

I've been running a prebuild event every time I do a build. It works perfectly:

```
"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\..\Tools\SubWCRev\SubWCRev" "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\.." "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Utilities\Revision\Revision.txt" "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Utilities\Revision\Revision.cs"
```

Now I'd like it to be only done if not DEBUG

```
if $(ConfigurationName) != Debug (
"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\..\Tools\SubWCRev\SubWCRev" "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\.." "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Utilities\Revision\Revision.txt" "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Utilities\Revision\Revision.cs"
)
```

But, VS2010 is telling me it exited with code 255. I can't figure out what that code means or why I'm having an issue.

I've tried adding double quotes around $(ConfigurationName) and Debug, tried playing around with new lines, etc, and even checking to see if it was Debug and doing exit0.

It seems my If is being ignored or trashed. How can I get this to run only if Non-Debug?

Comment: try moving it to a single line?

Comment: Yes, I haved tried doing it all on one line, removing the parens. no luck.

Comment: I think you might need quotes around Debug

Comment: No, I tried using quotes around the macro and "Debug", and that didn't do it.

Comment: Check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only there are mutliple ways mentioned in here.

Comment: I was previously on that question. I didn't  see the answer by @Franci Penov to set up a conditioned PropertyGroup. That was the only option that would work for me.