# How to automatically code-sign MSI built with WiX in VS 2010?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-installer, code-signing

I'm building my MSI project using Visual Studio 2010 and [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/). I'd like to automatically sign the release build upon successful compilation. (Note, not the `Debug` build though, to save on compilation time.)

So far, I added this "Post-build" event when 'Release' is selected in solution configuration:

[image]

Which translates into this command:

```
"D:\C++\My Project\MSI Installer\MyProject-Installer\..\..\..\CodeSigner.exe" "D:\C++\My Project\MSI Installer\MyProject-Installer\MyProject-Installer\bin\Release\MyProject-Installer.msi"
```

Well, the problem is that `$(TargetPath)` is not that. The actual path for the resulting `MSI` is this for US English build:

```
D:\C++\My Project\MSI Installer\MyProject-Installer\MyProject-Installer\bin\Release\en-us\MyProject-Installer.msi
```

**Issue 1:** You see the `\en-us` folder is somehow missing in what `$(TargetPath)` is filling out.

**Issue 2:** VS 2010 tries to run this post-build script for both `Release` and `Debug`. And I need it for `Release` only, like I was able to do with VS 2008.

So any idea how to fix these two issues?

Comment: For issue 2: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only.

Answer (score 0):

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\Blobs.msi" "$(SolutionDir)debugDir" /Y /r
) ELSE (
 xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\Blobs.msi" "$(SolutionDir)releaseDir" /Y /r
)
```